# My search feature has stopped functioning since I changed the item tags.

Tags: javascript, html, search

I have a list of items on a dropdown with a clickable button. They were originally in  tags but i had to change them to checkboxes to allow certain features. When I changed them my search feature stopped working. I have tried changing the search .js but am unable to figure out why it isn't working.

Here is my .html

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button type="button" id="hobbyFilter" onclick="openHobbyFilter()" class="dropbtn">Hobbies</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." id="myInput" onkeyup="filterFunction()">
    <input type="checkbox" id="hobbies" href="hobby">Hobby</input><br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="hobbies" href="cycling">Cycling</input><br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="hobbies" href="runing">Running</input><br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="hobbies" href="sky diving">Sky Diving</input><br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="hobbies" href="bmx">BMX</input><br>
  </div>
</div><br>
```

here is my .js

```
function filterFunction() {
      var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
      input = document.getElementById("myInput");
      filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
      div = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
      a = div.getElementsById("hobbies");
      for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (a[i].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
          a[i].style.display = "show";
        } else {
          a[i].style.display = "none";
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: `id`'s should be unique! If you wish to group elements then I would suggest you use a `class` name. **Also** `div.getElementsById("hobbies");` is incorrect. This will no doubt cause a syntax error since `javascript` expects `id`'s to be unique hence the use of `.getElementById()` -- **Element** By Id, not **Element(s)** By Id

Answer (score 0):

You can't get multiple ID's as they should be unique. Try to change them to classes and then change the `a = div.getElementsById("hobbies");` to `a = div.getElementsByClassName("hobbies");` like this:

```js
function filterFunction() {
      var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
      input = document.getElementById("myInput");
      filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
      div = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
      a = div.getElementsByClassName("hobbies");
      for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (a[i].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
          a[i].style.display = "show";
        } else {
          a[i].style.display = "none";
        }
      }
    }
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button type="button" id="hobbyFilter" onclick="openHobbyFilter()" class="dropbtn">Hobbies</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." id="myInput" onkeyup="filterFunction()">
    <input type="checkbox" class="hobbies" href="hobby">Hobby</input><br>
    <input type="checkbox" class="hobbies" href="cycling">Cycling</input><br>
    <input type="checkbox" class="hobbies" href="runing">Running</input><br>
    <input type="checkbox" class="hobbies" href="sky diving">Sky Diving</input><br>
    <input type="checkbox" class="hobbies" href="bmx">BMX</input><br>
  </div>
</div><br>
```

Comment: Okay I tried your suggestion and the search function is still not working. Also it made my checkboxes dissapear upon typing into the search bar.